# Confused about java assignment method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, data-structures

Hi guys so right now I'm taking data structures in school and I'm having trouble understanding the code our homework is based on which was created by the teacher.

Basically its a program designed to store integers and assign them sets depending on if their positive, negative, and a set that keeps track of weather or not the last entry of an integer was either. We have a class that creates a new array with the storage of whatever int is passed to it. We also have a insert method that inserts an int into a collection only if its not already there. heres the code:

```
public IntColl1(int i){
    c = new int[i+1];
    c[0] = 0;
}

public void insert(int i){
    if (i > 0){
        int j = 0;
        while ((c[j] != 0) && (c[j] != i)) j++;
        if (c[j] == 0){
            if (j == c.length - 1){
                int newLength = (c.length * 2);
                int[] d = new int[newLength];
                for(int l = 0; l < c.length; l++){
                    d[l] = c[l];
                }
                c = d;
            }
            c[j] = i;
            c[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Its supposed to insert the Int into the array and if the array is too small, it creates a new one with double the length. For test we set Intcoll1(1), Can anyone help by explaining the while loop that is inside the first if statement? I always thought that when an empty array is created that the slots were all set to 0, and if thats the case then wouldn't that while loop always be false?

Comment: Sorry! This my first question so still getting used to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the while loop is trying to find the next "available" space in the array. Initially (as you correctly stated) the while condition will immediately be false. After a couple of inserts, it will be more useful.

Assuming an initial array size of 5, `c` would start out looking like

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

If I call `insert(4)`, the condition

```
(c[j] != 0) && (c[j] != i)
```

Fails, so `j` is never incremented and 4 is inserted as position 0. Now `c` looks like

```
[4,0,0,0,0]
```

Now if I call `insert(7)`, the condition will be initially satisfied when `j` is 0, but will fail when `j` is incremented to one, so 7 will be inserted as position 1:

```
[4,7,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help by explaining the while loop that is inside the first if statement?

Well I feel that there is a problem in understanding your program above. So I am re-writing the code to make it clear to your:

```
public void insert(int i){
    if (i > 0){
        int j = 0;
        while ((c[j] != 0) && (c[j] != i)){ //Introduced this bracket to show the start of while
           j++;
        } //Introduced this bracket to show the end of while
        if (c[j] == 0){
            if (j == c.length - 1){
                int newLength = (c.length * 2);
                int[] d = new int[newLength];
                for(int l = 0; l < c.length; l++){
                    d[l] = c[l];
                }
                c = d;
            }
            c[j] = i;
            c[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The next if statement `if (c[j] == 0)` is not inside the `while` loop. Hope that now your understand it.

Comment: That was how it was given to us, i rewrote it adding the brackets but for this i just copied what our teacher gave to us

Comment: @10marcer So what is your problem in understanding it?